# Sort a list of objects and convert into a list of JObjects

Tags: c#, json, json.net, listobject

I'm new to C# programming and any help would appreciate. because this might be a simple thing to a c# developer. I have tried so many things but had type mismatches or compilation errors in Newtonsoft JObjects when I try to develop this.

I'm having a list of objects like

```
List<ContextResult> formOutputs ->

[0] = (section 1, Button, true),
[1] = (section 1, TextBox, anyname),
[2] = (section 2, Button, false)

public class ContextResult
    {
        public string Section { get; set; }
        public string Key{ get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to sort this into sections, and convert into a list of JObjects using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq. The output should look like this in JSON format,

```
"section 1":{
"Button": "true",
"TextBox": "anyname"
 },
"section 2":{
"Button": "false"
 }
```

please note that I have already ordered the formOutputs to ascending order and grouped using `GroupBy` to remove duplicates.

Comment: But your output isn‘t like JSON format. JSON format looks like `[{Object object},{Object object},{Object object}]`

Comment: @SwissCodeMen I'm sorry for that. I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working with JObjects I'd convert you data into desired structure and then just serialize it.

Here's how it can be done for your data:

```
var o = formOutputs
     .GroupBy(o => o.Section) 
     .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,g => g.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value));
```

Here's a version with comments:

```
var o = formOutputs
    .GroupBy( o => o.Section) // For the example data we now have groups: 'section 1', 'section 2'
    .ToDictionary( 
        keySelector: g => g.Key, // this 'Key' is the group's key (so o.Section), not the Key property of ContextResult
        elementSelector: g => g.ToDictionary( 
                keySelector: x =>  x.Key, 
                elementSelector: x => x.Value));
```

Test:

```
var formOutputs = new List<ContextResult> {
    new ContextResult { Section = "section 1", Key = "Button", Value = "true"},
    new ContextResult { Section = "section 1", Key = "TextBox",Value = "anyname"},
    new ContextResult { Section = "section 2", Key = "Button", Value = "false"}
    };

var o = formOutputs
    .GroupBy(o => o.Section) 
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,g => g.ToDictionary(x =>  x.Key, x => x.Value));    

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o, Formatting.Indented));
```

Output:

```
{
  "section 1": {
    "Button": "true",
    "TextBox": "anyname"
  },
  "section 2": {
    "Button": "false"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! You made my day. I was struggling with this for hours